# Hibernate query on custom collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have a hibernate mapping with custom collection types in it.

java:

```
class Policy {
...
private HistoryMap<Date, PolicyStatus> statusHistory;
...
}
```

hbm.xml:

```
    <map name="statusHistory" inverse="true" table="tbl_policy_in_time" order-by="PolIt_ValidFrom desc"
                    collection-type="be.pensionarchitects.admindb.infrastructure.hibernate.HistoryMapType">
                ...
    </map>
```

`HistoryMapType` is an implementation of interface `HistoryMap` and implements `UserCollectionType`.

This map has a method `getCurrent()` which returns the current `PolicyStatus`.

Now I need to do a query to get all Policy objects having a specific PolicyStatus as current one.

Something like:

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Policy.class)
                .createAlias("statusHistory.current", "status")
                .add(Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.eq("status.code", "active"),
                        Restrictions.eq("status.code", "sleeper")));
```

I understand this doesn't work as "current" isn't an association mapping. How i should I solve this? I have read that I should use HQL instead, but have no idea how and if it's even possible.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HistoryMap implements java.util.Map (and respects the interface's contracts) then you can use Criteria API. If not, I don't think it will work with HQL (and with Criteria API). In that case, using native SQL is your best bet. You can make a native query who's result is marshaleld to a specific Hibernate Bean:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696